# how to make a new NSDictionary from a NSDictionary where key = x

Tags: ios, json

i have a app that gets some json data from a mysql server via a web api like this:

```
[[API sharedInstance] commandWithParams:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"streamGames", @"command", nil] onCompletion:^(NSDictionary *json) {

    //got stream

     [[API sharedInstance] setGames:[json objectForKey:@"result"]];
```

this gives me :

```
{
    awayScor = 3;
    data = "2014-04-11";
    gameType = 1;
    homeScor = 2;
    homeTeam = "Herning Blue Fox";
    time = "21:00";
},
    {
    awayScor = 1;
    data = "2014-04-08";
    gameType = 2;
    homeScor = 2;
    homeTeam = "SønderjyskE";
    time = "19:00";
},
```

now what  i want to do i make a new NSDictionary where i only add data where lets say gameType = 1  so i have a new NSDictionary for etch gameType.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly!

```
NSArray *games; // Get this from somewhere
NSMutableDictionary *gameTypes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

for (NSDictionary *game in games) {
    NSNumber *gameType = game[@"gameType"];
    NSMutableArray *gamesForType = gameTypes[gameType];
    if (!gamesForType) {
        gamesForType = [NSMutableArray array];
        gameTypes[gameType] = gamesForType;
    }
    [gamesForType addObject:game];
}
```

Now `gameTypes` will be a dictionary of game types to an array games of that type.